Is it true that weeds prefer poor soil?
The Australian public broadcaster, the ABC, recently posted an article on how best to deal with weeds and this passage made me quite intrigued,

Nutrient-rich soil means fewer weeds, because, as Ms Wall explains, "most weeds prefer poor soil conditions".  "As I've improved my soil, I've certainly eliminated a whole suite of weeds, simply because they don't like good soil," she says.

This quote is provided by Meanjin/Brisbane-based horticulturist and "gardening coach" Kate Wall.
I am wondering how true this is?  I don't understand the biological mechanism of why weeds would struggle to grow in nutrient rich soil.

It depends.
Many weeds are ruderal species, so plants which grow in a disturbed land with few vegetation. Usually annual, fast growing and they make a lot of seed (usually to find an other ruderal space). So they like our gardens, streets, etc. where they have not much competition, where other plants may growth better (slowly, but with stronger roots, more green, etc.). And so they are weeds.
On the other hand we have also weeds which prefer rich soil. Nettles are one of such plants. In such case, the disturbed was excess of nutrients, e.g. neat animal stalls. Note: there you will find many other weeds (so plants which animals will not eat).
I do not think the quote is right. The prefer doesn't mean they cannot live successfully on other soils, as you see in vegetable gardens: disturbed (not much vegetation to block seed and seedling to growth), but for sure fertile soils, and a lot of weeds. And nettles may not growth (usually in vegetable gardens) because they are slow (compared most vegetable and managing of the vegetable garden).
Note: there are exceptions. In my region, on mountains, some local but invasive ferns dislike fertile soil (but I think it is most about pH, and high pH may inhibit many plants).
